# Some ToC & page numbering questions

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering, front-matter

I am just in the last stages of sorting out a book for my publishers.  The main problems are with page numbering, and ToC.

The publishers require:

1. Table of contents (numbered with Roman numerals)
2. a blank page (unnumbered)
3. the preface (start numbering again)
4. a blank page (unnumbered)
5. start of main matter (numbered with arabic numerals)

What I have done is:

```
\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{empty}

\newpage\mbox{}\newpage

\pagestyle{headings}

\include{ch_preface}
```

However, what happens is that the last page of the ToC is not numbered, nor is the first page of the preface.  On the other hand, the blank page between the ToC and the preface *is* numbered.  Can anyone advise me?

One other problem is that appendices are to appear in the ToC as

Appendix A This is the first Appendix
A.1  etc

That is, the word "Appendix" must appear before the appendix roman numeral.  What is the canonical way to achieve this?

The last ToC problem is that the publishers want a row of dots in the ToC for the "Bibliography" and "Index", even though these are treated by LaTeX as being chapter headings, rather than sections.  Again, how do I achieve this?

Comment: `\pagestyle{empty}` changes the pagestyle from the current page on. You are probably looking for `\newpage\mbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage`. See also http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=reallyblank

Answer (score 4):

what facilities are available depend on what document class you are using.  some classes provide "super-sectioning" of a book into `\frontmatter` (automatic roman page numbers), `\mainmatter` (restarts page number at 1 and resets font to arabic), and `\backmatter` (clears any "leftovers" from `appendix`).  `\appendix` is often set up to reset the `\chaptername` to "Appendix"; this flows automatically into the table of contents.  look to see what's defined in the document class.

regarding blank pages without running heads, this is what the ams has done to make this happen automatically:

```
\let\cleardouble@page\cleardoublepage
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifx\cleardouble@page\cleardoublepage
    \def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardouble@page}}
  \fi
}
```

it can safely be used at the end of any chapter or other appropriate segment (like the toc) and will always result in the next "real" output starting on a right-hand page.

ams style doesn't use dots in the toc, so i'll leave that part of the question for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\pagestyle{headings}
\chapter*{Preface}

\lipsum
\lipsum


\pagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{test}
\lipsum
\lipsum


\end{document}
```

There is just one point: the blank page between the toc and the preface is numbered, even though the page number is not printed. What you could do to fix that is use another counter for the preface, such as `Roman`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\chapter*{Preface}

\lipsum
\lipsum


\pagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{test}
\lipsum
\lipsum


\end{document}
```